# Number sign/Hash in filename of file URI

Tags: html, windows, uri, internet-explorer-11

I have the following file:

```
C:\path\to\abc#123.txt
```

I develop web front-end for IE11 on Windows that presents link to that file. I use the following URI encoding the `#` with `%23`:

```
file:\\\c:\path\to\abc%23123.txt
```

On clicking on the link IE11 treats the `#` as HTML fragment/anchor not as part of the filename and the file ist not opened. How can I enforce using the encoded `%23` to be part of the filename? If I enter the URI manually in the browser bar the file is opened as expected.

**Update:**

It works if the link target is set to `_parent` or `_top` but does not work when set to `_blank` (what I need it to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using JavaScript for the onclick event of the link:

```
var doc = window.open();
doc.location.href = "file:\\\c:\path\to\abc%23123.txt";
return false;
```

This opens a new window a required and then sets the URI with number sign.